# Increase font size when screen is smaller

Tags: c#, xaml, fonts, win-universal-app

I have this in my `XAML`

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.4*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.4*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Column="1">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.5*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.5*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Row="1" >
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Hello there and welcome!" />
        </Grid>
        </Grid>
</Grid>
```

The problem I'm facing is that the `TextBlock` will remain the same `FontSize` on all screen sizes, so when the screen is small, its easy to read but as the screen gets bigger its harder to read.

How do I keep it at a nice `FontSize` so it's readable from all screen sizes? Is there a way of increasing the font size as the screen expands?

Comment: Users with big screens [do this](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/change-your-monitors-dots-per-inch-dpi-setting.html).

Comment: @HansPassant Good banter :|

Comment: Just curious. What's the font size and what device of the bigger screen did you use?

Comment: I haven't set the font size as it would be fixed. The screen is the standard emulator, when it's minimized the font remains the same size rather than getting bigger to be displayed in a clear readable format @JustinXL

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap it inside the ViewBox

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
    <Viewbox>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Hello there and welcome!" />
    </Viewbox>
</Window>
```

Comment: I've wrapped in within a `ViewBox` . In portrait mode, the font size is ridiculously small

Answer (score 0):

WPF fonts are DPI aware, so they'll be the same size regardless of resolution. A viewbox will allow you to scale everything down to fit, although in my experience it typically results in everything looking too small, especially if it's been designed on a desktop and then viewed on a laptop. What I do myself is create two themes and choose the appropriate one based on physical display size (i.e. product of DPI and resolution). Not sure if it's the best solution, but so far it seems to be working.

Comment: I'll note that the question is about Universal apps, not WPF. I don't know if that matters for your answer.